# Transfering files to MTP-Device from Windows via commandline

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer, mtp

I am searching for a way to transfer files form my PC to a MTP-Device (No Android) using batch-file (command line). Is there any command line based application which can just transfer files from PC to MTP Device.

P.S: I have already read most solutions in net, most of them ended up using samba and WebDev, but i can not do that. since it's a client project.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the steps below

1. Go to Command prompt
2. Enter `cd "file location"`
3. `adb push "filename" /mnt/sdcard/`

Verification steps:

```
adb root
adb shell
cd /mnt/sdcard
ls
```

Comment: OP mentioned that the device is not Android.